# Modification of the 0 1 Knapsack Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

How would we approach to a 0 1 Knapsack Problem if we have items that can be picked multiple times. For example we have 5 items with weights 6, 5, 4, 2, 1 and their respective weights are 6.59, 6.49, 6.39, 6.29, 6.16. Now the allowed weight to pick up is 10.

The variation is we can pick any item any number of time and then maximise the value. How do we approach this.? Any suggestions or articles is really appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Please choose one tag and remove the others.

Comment: @AshishAcharya I tried forming an algorithm using the fundamental Knapsack solutions. But I could not find that really helpful. I don't need a solution code. I just a simple approach or any explanation which tells which algorithm will it use.

Comment: @Ron Can you please suggest which tag would be better to use.? I used the 5 most important languages used for competitive programming so that I can convey the problems to maximum coders.

Comment: @PriytoshTripathi "*And I didn't find any tag regarding algorithms*" <- found it for you, it's called [tag:algorithm].

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thank you. That's really kind you.

Comment: @PriytoshTripathi I **guess** you won't have much luck with this question here anyways ... probably fewer people will follow just "algorithm" as SO really has a focus on actual **code** (but that's no reason to spam language tags). And then, I don't understand the question, but that might be just me. Finally, you ask for "articles", that's off-topic on SO (asking for an off-site resource). Good luck anyways.

Comment: @FelixPalmen This is just a simple modification of the 0 1 Knapsack problem. The modification is that you can pick an item any number of times. Like there is a store with unlimited articles. And they have five variety of article. You can buy 5 identical articles or 5 different type of articles. Just keep the value maximum. 
If this makes it easier. Anyways thanks for your suggestions and effort in giving up a right tag. I highly acknowledge it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already solved 0/1 Knapsack problem using Genetic algorithm, this [tutorial](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat1.html) will give an introduction to this topic including an example (in C++) that will get you started.

If you want to have an idea on how to solve the mentioned problem, you can give a try to these link:

- [Solving the Knapsack Problem with a Simple Genetic Algorithm](http://www.dataminingapps.com/2017/03/solving-the-knapsack-problem-with-a-simple-genetic-algorithm/)
- [Genetic Algorithm for Knapsack Problem](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607791/ga-knapsack)

You may use other techniques to solve the problem, but I see using GA as a very interesting thing to do.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will get into the article. Although the heading seems convincing.